# Passing different arguments in a function with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a GUI tool using powershell that will pull message tracking information from an exchange server. Based on what the user selects will determine the type of search. If not all the args are passed when Get-MessageTrackingLog is run, will the command simply remove that parameter or pass a null value?
Example: if nothing gets passed to "-sender $sender" will the value simply be "null" or will the parameter also be removed, like this?

Get-MessageTrackingLog -server $hts -sender $sender # a value is being passed
or
Get-MessageTrackingLog -server $hts                 # no value for sender is passed

In other words, if I don't pass an arg with a parameter, then I don't want that parameter to be included in the command.

I'm trying to avoid having to write get-messagetrackinglog for every different scenario based on the user's selection.

Hopefully this makes sense to everyone, thanks!

```
If ($sender -and $chk_Mailbox.checked -and $chk_End.checked -and $chk_start.checked){Msg -sender **$sender** -Start **$Start** -End **$End** -max_res_size **$max_res_size**}
If ($sender -and $chk_Mailbox.checked -and (!$chk_End.checked) -and (!$chk_start.checked)){Msg -sender $sender -max_res_size **$max_res_size**}

Function Msg{
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
[Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$false)]
$Sender,
[Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$false)]
$Start,
[Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$false)]
$End,
[Parameter(Position=3,Mandatory=$true)]
$max_res_size,
[Parameter(Position=4,Mandatory=$false)]
$EventID,
[Parameter(Position=5,Mandatory=$false)]
$MsgID
)
    BEGIN
    {
        If ($max_res_size -match "unlimited"){$maxloop = 100000000} else {$maxloop = $max_res_size}

        $ht = Get-ExchangeServer | ?{$_.admindisplayversion -match '14.3' -and $_.ServerRole -match 'HubTransport'}  |% {$_.name} 
        $startstop = $true
    Foreach ($hts in $ht)
        {
            Get-MessageTrackingLog -server $hts -sender **$sender** -Start **$Start** -End **$End** -resultsize **$max_res_size** -EventID **$EventID** -MessageId **$MsgID** -warningaction 0 |
            %{
                if ($rescount -ge $maxloop){$startstop = $false; break}
                $dataGridView1.rows.add($_.TimeStamp,$_.Sender,[string]$_.Recipients,$_.RecipientCount,`
                $_.TotalBytes,$_.ReturnPath,$_.MessageLatency,$_.MessageLatencyType,$_.EventId,$_.Source,$_.ServerHostname,$_.ConnectorId,$_.MessageId)
                $rescount++
                $Res_Count.text = $rescount
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Matt So, it would look like this:  `Get-MessageTrackingLog @MsgTrkParm
 $MsgTrkParm = @{'sender' = $Sender;
  'server' = $HTS;
  'Start' = $Start;
        'end' = $End;
  'EventID' = $EventID}`

Comment: See my answer where I try and cover that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx). It is a handy way to conditionally build a set of parameters for cmdlet calls.

Just to show you one as an example

```
$parameters = @{
    Server = $hts
    Start = $Start
    End = $End
    ResultSize = $max_res_size
    EventID = $EventID
    MessageId = $MsgID
    WarningAction = 0
}

# If sender was specified then add it as a parameter
if($sender){$parameters.Sender = $sender}

# Call the cmdlets passing all the arguments we used. 
Get-MessageTrackingLog @parameters
```

I know that you would want to make other optional as well. Easy to replicate from what I have shown you here. Basically take a hashtable that you define and build as you check your other parameters. Then you [splat that](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) to the cmdlet `Get-MessageTrackingLog`

Also keep in mind that you can just use default values for some of these inside your `param` so that way you do not have to check if they exist.

This is also a handy way to keep lines short when you have a lot of parameters. Save the backticks use splatting.

Comment: I now here Usher saying "Splat that" inside my head.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is exactly how it works. A parameter that is not bound to a value will have the default value for that type (or a default value that is specified for that parameter, if present). For reference types or parameters that don't have a specific type, this is `$null`.

So for a function

```
function x($a, $b){}
x 1
```

you'd have `$b` equal to `$null`, but in the following case

```
function x($a, [int]$b){}
x 1
```

it'd be `0` instead. And for this:

```
function x($a, $b=-1){}
x 1
```

you'd get `-1` because there's a specific default value specified.